# Replace all unicode parts of text to normal text in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, unicode

So I have this richtextbox with normal text and then some unicode parts in between like

> This is a text \u0061

But with a lot of more lines and unicode in between. 
I got the code for converting those into normal strings where the actual characters being shown from the MSDN

I would need to take the 0061 from the `\u0061` and put it into my function to convert it.

The problem is, how can I **efficiently** go through that text and replacing the unicodes with the normal characters at the exact place where they should be?

Possibilities:
- Should I use RegEx and go through the whole text 
Or
- Is there a way to replace those parts with some easier text manipulation?

Comment: This page on MSDN provides code to convert an entire string - adaptable to convert RTB lines - to ascii. ... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdcak6ye%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 ...Then you just need to iterate through the lines in the RTB

Comment: Yeah, I know, this is the code I am using. I am thinking about how to efficiently iterate through the text, please read the original post carefully (again)

Comment: I read it carefully the first time and noticed that you provided no code to indicate what you had done already.  Please read [mcve] carefully. If you had read the help pages to find out what is on topic you would have noticed that asking for help to write code is not what this website is about. It is for people who have written code, can't get it working properly and are able to post code, expected behaviour and actual behaviour. All of these comments would have been unnecessary if you had done that.

Comment: OK. That said. If the text is long enough, you might also be better off reading the lines into an array and iterating through it using Parallel.For or Parallel.ForEach

Comment: Can you give me a brief explanation on how to read the text into an array and doing the Parallel.ForEach thing? I am still trying to figure out a way to do all this efficiently

Comment: Sure. Are you able to add couple of sample pararaphs please?

Comment: Also how long is the text files in its complete state?

Comment: Hi again.. Do you have some sample text that you can add to your question so that I can try some code?